# Почему не cтоит использовать fallback и ловить обобщённый Exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения

Есть приблизительно такой код:

```
def func(self, args):
    try:
        # some operators  
    except SomeKindOfException1 as e:
        # some action 1
    except SomeKindOfException2 as e:
        # some action 2
    except SomeKindOfException3 as e:
        # some action 3                       
    except Exception as e:
        # some action 4
```

Объясните пожалуйста, по какой причине не стоит использовать последний блок исключения:

```
except Exception as e:
    # some action 4
```

Насколько понимаю, он выполняет роль fallback и ничего плохого в этом я не вижу.

Answer (score 6):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553825/1991579

Не думаю, что python в этом плане отличается от других языков. Если вы используете `try` вы ожидаете конкретных исключений. Если в `try` у вас парсится `int` из строки, то вы ожидаете `ValueError`, если читаете файл, то можете словить `FileNotFoundError`.

Когда вы ловите `Exception`, то это означает, что случилась незапланированная ошибка, которую вы, вполне вероятно, не сможете нормально обработать.

В питоне есть [`SystemError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemError), случающиеся редко, но которые в принципе почти не реально обработать. Если вы такое будете ловить в блоке с `Exception`, то у вас приложение может оказаться в не консистентном состоянии.

Comment: Позволю себе не согласиться. При наличии гирлянды возможных `Exception` с одинаковой реакцией на каждый, проще и короче указать просто `Exception`. Также совсем нехорошо, когда в Вашей программе, работающей в фоне в многопоточном режиме, потоки начинают с грохотом валиться по непредусмотренной Вами причине и даже не могут сбросить в лог, что же с ними случилось. Я считаю, что любой серьёзный код должен быть обрамлён `try:` - `except Exception as e:` с логированием того, что случилось и последующим graceful завершением...

Comment: @SergeyNudnov фоновые сервисы работают под супервизором. Если в программе произошла внештатная ситуация, то некоторые не считают, что её лучше грохнуть и перезапустить. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash-only_software

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется, ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553825/1991579 совершенно не отражает суть вопроса.

Я согласен, что:

```
try:
    ...
except:
    pass
```

это зло.

Но совсем нехорошо, когда в программе, работающей в фоне в многопоточном режиме, потоки начинают с грохотом валиться по непредусмотренной причине и даже не могут сбросить в лог, что же с ними случилось.

Я считаю, что любой серьёзный код должен быть обрамлён:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(e.args)
```

с логированием того, что случилось и последующим graceful завершением...

Comment: Такое допустимо только в том случае, если после записи в лог идёт оператор `raise` для повторного выброса возникшего исключения. Но лучше просто перенаправлять в файл стандартный поток вывода ошибок. Что касается "graceful завершения", _спасательные операции_ надо выполнять в обработчиках `atexit`, а не обработчиках _широких_ исключений.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Чем будет отличаться самый наружный обработчик широких исключений от обработчика atexit? По-моему, ничем существенным. Кроме того, что в обработчике atexit придётся проверять, нормально мы выходим или по исключению. Насчет `raise` - в функциях да, лучше ставить.

Comment: Тем, что логика, отвечающая за нормальное завершение работы, расположена в одном, специально предназначенном для этого месте, а не размазана по всему коду.

Answer (score -1):

Использование Exception в вашем примере абсолютно правильно и оправдано, тк определяет поведение в случае непредвиденной ошибки, совместно в иными типами ошибок. Неправильное использование это когда есть только один блок except с Exception.

`as e:` для вывода ошибки делать необязательно, в logging есть специальный аргумент `exc_info` который сделает все сам.

```
import logging
try:
    raise UserWarning('text_1')
except:
    logging.error('text_2', exc_info=True)

ERROR:root:text_2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/SCR/NEW_STAND/sdafsdaf.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise UserWarning('text_1')
UserWarning: text_1
```